# Convert hourly date %Y/%m/%d to %Y/%m/%d %H:%M in r

Tags: r, datetime

I have a data frame that consists of hourly time series, but my problem is that the format is %Y/%m/%d, meaning that each date repeats 24 times. I can't seem to figure out how to add the hour property to my date object. This is an example:

```
Date
1997/01/01
1997/01/01
1997/01/01
1997/01/01
1997/01/01
1997/01/01
1997/01/01
1997/01/01
1997/01/01
1997/01/01
1997/01/01
1997/01/01
1997/01/01
1997/01/01
1997/01/01
1997/01/01
1997/01/01
1997/01/01
1997/01/01
1997/01/01
1997/01/01
1997/01/01
1997/01/01
1997/01/01
```

I tried adding +3600 to each row but I only got:

```
Date
1997-01-01 01:00:00
1997-01-01 01:00:00
1997-01-01 01:00:00
1997-01-01 01:00:00
1997-01-01 01:00:00
```

I would like to end up with something like this in each row:

```
1997/01/01 00:00
1997/01/01 01:00
1997/01/01 02:00
1997/01/01 03:00
...
```

So I could aggregate the data from hourly to daily. I looked into previous posts but didn't have any luck. Any hint of help would be very appreciated. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```r
library(lubridate)
df$Date + hours(((1:length(df$Date) -1 ) %% 24 + 1))
```

It will work if your `Date` column is already formatted as date (use `ymd()` or `as.Date()`)

Comment: That did the trick, thank you @eastclintw00d. I just had a small mistmatch with the date but maybe because in some part there is a repeated date, but I can solve that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In base R you can use recycling technique to add hours.

```
df$Date <- as.POSIXct(df$Date) + 0:23 * 3600
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option with `anytime`

```
library(anytime)
df$Date <- anytime(df$Date) + (3600 * (0:23))
```